# How many groupings of 5 vectors are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Studying Linear Algebra by Robert Messer, came across an exercise I cannot solve.

Write down the ways of grouping the sum of five factors.

The book shows all the groupings written down, but my question is: How can I calculate the number of ways I can sum 5 vectors?

I thought about calculating in how many ways I can group them using combinations, but not sure about that.

EDIT: 
Example: Two different groupings would be...
$$u+(v+(w+(x+y)))$$ and $$(((u+v)+w)+x)+y$$

Comment: could you make it clear what exactly you mean by a "way of grouping". Perhaps an example. e.g. are there 3 ways of grouping the sum of 3 vectors or are there more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we require is the number of opening parentheses is at least the number of closing parentheses.  Since adding five addends requires four binary operations, we need four sets of parentheses.  Such sequences of parentheses are counted by the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).
$$C_n = \binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n + 1} = \frac{1}{n + 1}\binom{2n}{n}$$
For $n = 4$, we obtain
$$C_4 = \frac{1}{5}\binom{8}{4} = 14$$
The groupings are:
\begin{align*}
& (((())))\\
& ((()()))\\ 
& ((())())\\ 
& ((()))()\\ 
& (()(()))\\ 
& (()()())\\ 
& (()())()\\ 
& (())(())\\
& (())()()\\
& ()((()))\\
& ()(()())\\
& ()(())()\\
& ()()(())\\
& ()()()()
\end{align*}

Comment: It seems we are all thinking differently about what is intended here. Your formula gives $C_3=5$ . In my way of thinking about this $C_3=3$ , the groupings being $(a+b)+c, (a+c)+b, (b+c)+a$ . how would you express your five groupings ?

Comment: @WW1 $C_3$ counts the number of ways of using three sets of parentheses to group four addends without changing the order of the addends:  $$(((a + b) + c) + d), (a + (b + c)) +d), ((a + b) + (c + d)), (a + ((b + c) + d), (a + (b + (c + d)))$$  We need three sets of parentheses for four addends since we must perform three binary operations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N_k $ represent the number of ways of grouping the sum of $k$ vectors

We can agree that $N_1=N_2=1$

for a sum of 3 vectors the final grouping must always be $2+1$

$\binom 32 $ ways of choosing the last grouping

$N_2 N_1$ ways of grouping within the final 2 groups

So $$ N_3=\binom 32 N_1N_2=3$$

For a sum of four vectors, the final grouping can be either $2+2$ or $3+1$
So $$ N_4=\binom 42 N_2N_2  + \binom 43 N_3N_1$$

Similarly
 $$ N_5=\binom 53 N_3N_2  + \binom 54 N_4N_1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(u+v)+((w+x)+y)\\
(u+v)+(w+(x+y))\\
((u+v)+w)+(x+y)\\
(u+(v+w))+(x+y)\\
u+(5 possibilities)\\
(5 possibilities)+y$$

Comment: so with your way of interpreting this question five vectors must always be written in the same order e.g. $(u+x)+((v+w)+y)$ would not be a valid grouping. So for 3 vectors, you would have only 2 valid groupings .

Comment: I can see now that the OP made an edit that suggests that your interpretation is actually what was intended.